# SDL Web8 & DXA - Dependency Missing in dxa-example-webapp

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, web8

1. Downloaded and accessed **DXA** installation media.
2. From the `cms\` folder, copied the `DXA Application Data Definition.xml` file to `%TRIDION_HOME%\config\ImportExport\ApplicationData\`.
3. Ran the `ttm-prepare.ps1` script and preconfigured the Topology Manager for the DXA Site Type and Business Process Types.
4. Ran `cms-import.ps1` script specifying each parameter-value pair in the format `-parameter "value"`.

   > .\cms-import.ps1 -importType all-publications -cmsUrl
   >   "https://localhost:81/"
5. Ran "**cms-import.ps1**" again and specified the following parameters to set Rights and Permissions for the default User Groups on the imported content:

   > .\cms-import.ps1 -importType rights-permissions -cmsUrl
   >   "https://localhost:81/"

   Confirmed that the import created new Publications and assigned security.

[image]

then i tried to compile the "dxa-example-webapp" by running command

> "mvn clean package -Pcd-web8"

and build failed because of following dependencies could not be resolved.

[image]

Tried the corrected maven command with build profile "web8" as:

> `mvn clean package -Pweb8`

[image]

And the same problem persists...

Comment: the documentation seems to contain a typo on the profile, it should be: `mvn clean package -P web8`, but when I do that I'm also not able to build the `dxa-example-webapp`, so will have to check it out.

Comment: Yeah that's right i checked it into maven pom file, profile is "web8" instead of "cd-web8"...its a typo..i tried it with mvn clean package -Pweb8..it runs the correctly matched profile from pom..but still dependencies missing problem persists.. @BartKoopman

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be version mismatches between the referenced 8.1.1 CIL artifacts and the ones available on Maven Central.
Furthermore, DXA uses a custom build of DD4T which needs to be registered in your local Maven repository.

In general, it may be easiest to obtain the sources from the dxa-web-application-java repository on GitHub (this includes the custom DD4T build) and build from there.

Answer (score 2):

It seems dd4t artifacts are not in DXA distribution. Since they're custom, they're not available on Maven Central. Thus you cannot resolve them.

The correct command is `mvn clean package -Pweb8` which points webapp to the right versions of CIL and DD4T. `web8` profile is a default so it's activated if Maven is run without any valid profile. This means `mvn clean package` is **exactly** the same command for this webapp. The profile `cd-web8` doesn't exist, so Maven actually executed `mvn clean package -Pweb8` because it's default.

The actual problem is that DD4T custom artifacts couldn't be resolved. They are on GitHub, and webapp is configured to **also** use `file:///${project.basedir}/../local-project-repo` as a Maven repository. It is there for GitHub and its clones, but it's not there for ZIP distribution. Once they're failed to be resolved, *the attempt is cached*!

1. The simplest solution is to copy all contents of https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/tree/release/1.4/local-project-repo to your `.m2/repository` folder. Don't forget to clear Maven cache (simply remove the whole `.m2/repository`)
2. The right solution is to put the `local-project-repo` folder next to your webapp. Also don't forget to clear Maven cache.
3. The additional solution is to add a remote repository on GitHub https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/release/1.4/local-project-repo using Maven's `<repositories/>` tag.

Comment: My maven project "dxa-example-website" has nothing in src/main/webapp folder. Everytime i am trying to build and run the project, it show assets/css/main.css not found and breaks.